# From a list of dictionaries, get all dictionaries where key column has highest severity values

Tags: python

Given a list of dictionaries as the one below:

```py
dictionaries = [
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 4, 'threshold': 0.25}
]
```

I want a final list of dictionaries with the highest `'severity'` value for each `'column'` key. For example:

The output from the above should be:

```py
output = [{'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}, 
          {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 4, 'threshold': 0.25}]
```

Because for `NRX_TOTAL` column the highest `'severity'` is 3, and for `TRX_Total` column it is 4.

Below there is a code snippet, which does the job. Any ideas on how can be improved?

```py
l_measure_thresholds_with_highest_severity_temp = []
l_disctinct_column_value = []

for l_dict in dictionaries:
    l_temp_dict = {'column': '', 'severity': 0, 'threshold': 0}
    x = l_dict['column']
    if x not in l_disctinct_column_value:
        l_disctinct_column_value.append(x)
        l_temp_dict['column'] = x
        l_measure_thresholds_with_highest_severity_temp.append(l_temp_dict)

l_measure_thresholds_with_highest_severity = list()

for i in l_measure_thresholds_with_highest_severity_temp:
    l_temp_dict = {'column': '', 'severity': 0, 'threshold': 0}
    dict_i_col = i['column']
    dict_i_sev = i['severity']
    dict_i_threshold = i['threshold']

    for j in dictionaries:   
        dict_j_col = j['column']
        dict_j_sev = j['severity']
        dict_j_threshold = j['threshold']
        if dict_i_col == dict_j_col:
            if dict_i_sev < dict_j_sev:
                l_highest_severity = dict_j_sev
                l_highest_threshold = dict_j_threshold
            else:
                l_highest_severity = dict_i_sev
                l_highest_threshold = dict_i_threshold
            l_temp_dict['column'] = dict_i_col
            l_temp_dict['severity'] = l_highest_severity
            l_temp_dict['threshold'] = l_highest_threshold
    l_measure_thresholds_with_highest_severity.append(l_temp_dict)
    
print(l_measure_thresholds_with_highest_severity)
```

Comment: why is it not the correct way in your opinion? what is missing?

Comment: @Gulzar , I think there must be a better /more pythonic way to do this .

Comment: I think what you are looking for was already answered here:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary>

Comment: @HubDanDevMan , No that is different thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new mapping between the `'column`' and the dict with the max severity for that column. To achieve that, it is helpful to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for the first comparison:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

severities = defaultdict(lambda: {'severity': 0})

for d in dictionaries:
    column = d['column']
    if d['severity'] > severities[column]['severity']:
        severities[column] = d

print(list(severities.values()))
```

The `defaultdict` is used for the first comparison to create a "dummy" dict with severity 0. Then, whenever a dict with the same column with a greater severity is found, it is saved in the `severities` dict. In the end, we just print the `values` which are the original dicts from the list.

On your list of dictionaries, the above will give:

```
[{'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}, 
 {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 4, 'threshold': 0.25}]
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do the thing:

```
a = [
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}
]

list_ = []
high_num = 0
for item in a:
    if item['severity'] > high_num:
        high_num = item['severity']
for item in a:
    if item['severity'] == high_num:
        list_.append(item)

print(list_)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic function that you could use:

```
a = [
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}
]


def max_group_by(lst, group, value):
    '''
    calculatie max values by group key within dict d
    '''
    result = []
    groups = []
    for d in lst:
        g = d.get(group)
        if g and g not in groups:
            v = d.get(value)
            groups.append(g)
            glist = [d2 for d2 in lst if d2.get(group) == g]
            maxval = max(glist, key=lambda x: x.get(value))
            result.append(maxval)
    return result

print(max_group_by(a, 'column', 'severity'))
# [{'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}, 
#  {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pandas solution:

`> pip install pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionaries)

max_per_column = df.groupby(["column"], sort=False)["severity"].transform(max)
ind = max_per_column == df["severity"]
result = df[ind]
```

this is as simple as your problem definition:

1. group by `column`
2. find max `severity` per group
3. get all rows with those max values
4. profit

Answer (score 0):

You can use sorting the list and getting the last value:

```
b = sorted(a,key=lambda x: x['severity'])[-1]
print(b)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output

Comment: this is O(n log n) which is not needed

Answer (score 0):

I gues you can sort like this:

```
a = [
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}
]

def key(elem):
    return elem['severity']

a.sort(key=key, reverse=True)
print(a)
```

look up what `sort()` does (it sorts by key)

Comment: this is O(n log n) which is not needed

Comment: No... the expected output is `[{'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}, {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
a = [
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}
]

output = []
severity = 0

for data in a:
    if data["severity"] > severity:
        output = []
        severity = data["severity"]
        output.append(data)
    elif data["severity"] == severity:
        output.append(data)
print(output)
```

**Output**:

```
[{'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}, {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following not the best solution (see Tomerikoo's for better alternative):

```
a = [  {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 1, 'threshold': 0.1},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 2, 'threshold': 0.15},
    {'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25},
    {'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 4, 'threshold': 0.25}
]

NRX_TOTAL = 0
NRX_DICT = None
TRX_TOTAL = 0
TRX_DICT = None

for i in a:
    if 'NRX_TOTAL' in i.values():
        if i['severity'] > NRX_TOTAL:
            NRX_TOTAL = i['severity']
            NRX_DICT = i
    else:
        if i['severity'] > TRX_TOTAL:
            TRX_TOTAL = i['severity']
            TRX_DICT = i

print([NRX_DICT, TRX_DICT])
```

Alternative:

```
d = set(map(lambda x: x['column'], a))
l = []

for i in d:
    l.append(max(filter(lambda x: i in x.values(), a), key=lambda x: x['severity']))

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[{'column': 'NRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 3, 'threshold': 0.25}, 
{'column': 'TRX_TOTAL', 'severity': 4, 'threshold': 0.25}]
```